# Android - How to store Address to DB

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, ormlite

Looking to store android.location.Address to a SQLite database. I am using ORMLite to persist my objects. ORMLite can persist Serializable items (as a BLOB I believe) but I think the only way to get something Serializable from an Address is to write it into a Parcel. Then I took a look at Parcel here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html and it says it should not be used for general purpose Serialization mechanism. So I am just wondering what the best practice for doing this would be. I do not want to store the Address in contacts, strictly in my SQLite database. I am currently doing this with my own Address class (very simple) but would prefer to use the built in Android class for this.

thanks

Comment: I'd encourage you to also ask the question on the ORMLite mailing list @Alex.  http://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-user/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the user list was to define a companion object that will be stored to the database and do the translation to/from the `android.location.Address` object by hand -- unfortunately.  This will allow you to manager the storing of the various `Address` fields to the database without worrying about forwards and backwards compatibility with other Android versions.

Here's the [discussion on the ormlite-user mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-user/browse_thread/thread/e37af1afd30d700/d25453e1a90fa9ed?lnk=gst&q=address#d25453e1a90fa9ed).