# SQLite: persistent storage of object instances

Tags: android, sqlite

I started using a SQLite database in my android application. Very simple to use for storing text, integer values or blobs.

question: how to store an object, e.g. android.location.Location ?

do i have to use serialization or parcable? i've read that parcable must not be used for persistent data storage. but location does not implement serializable.

any difference between storing instances of API classes and my own one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't come up with good designs/reason to do so for "normal" apps. Could you explain what you are trying to do and why you would want to save a Location object in your database?

Comment: so far i just have to compute the distance between the current location and locations saved by the user. i thought it would be the best solution to simply store the location objects... besides that i would like to know if there is a good solution to store instances of API classes (that are not serializable) into a sqlite database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Android - How to store Address to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689036/android-how-to-store-address-to-db).  You might want to persist just the attributes you care about, and reconstruct Location from them later.  For example, storing latitude and longitude if they are all you care about.

Comment: I would have liked if it was possible to simply restore the location object with all attributes provided by the underlying hardware instead of storing them manually and restore them using all the setters. but i found a workaround: as long as i just want to compute the distance i will use 'static void distanceBetween' http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29 provided by the Location class - and store latitude and longitude by myself